# meteor: how to disable default mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, javascript-framework

in my meteor project, how can i remove or disable the default mongdodb?

```
.meteor/local/db/...
```

it's very large about 500MB! and i want exclude this from my project because use another external db

Answer (score 1):

You can clear it out with a `meteor reset` (or `mrt reset` if you are using meteorite). By default you should have a `.meteor/.gitignore` file which will ignore the entire `.meteor/local` directory from your git repository. Of course, you will need something a little different if you use another version control system.

Comment: I'm use mercurial! I did not understand, meteor read the file .gitignore for ignore db after I reset?

Comment: meteor does not use the `.gitignore` file - it's just there for people using git so they don't accidentally check in their database. Since you are using mercurial, just add a `.hgignore`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Meteor command line tool is hardcoded to run mongo. You might be able to specify a dummy MONGO_URL to avoid connecting to a database if you don't want to.

```
// Running meteor without a database
MONGO_URL=none meteor
```

If you pass a string different than none, it won't start during production.
This question was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545905/meteor-without-mongo).

Comment: I get a " Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb" wen MONGO_URL is set to none