# MeteorJs MongoDB production deployment

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to MeteorJS and I have a few nagging questions.

If these are overly simplistic forgive me. :)

Background: I would like to use this framework to write a mobile app (no web side as of yet) and hit my existing RESTful endpoints for data querying and CRUD.

Since I do not need a database (bc I already have one connected to my other backend) **how can I go about removing or turning off MongoDb?** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546761/4144) SO answer and I remove the `meteor-platform` but it somehow gets added back in. (Just doing the standard `meteor create --example todos`)

If I am unable to turn the Mongo functionality off, would there be any downside to keeping it there and just never using it?

Lastly, what happens when I deploy my MeteorJS app to iOS/Android with respect to the MongoDb I was using locally? I assume there is a hole somewhere that I supply a URI to so that that app knows how to get to it? I can't find this place if such a thing exists.

Comment: I think that would remove my main reason for wanting to use Meteor in the first place and thats its ease of producing ios/android applications from js/html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use any of meteor's server functionality (login, publish, methods) then there is no way for your client application to find out that the server has not been started.

You can safely use [HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http) on the client to use your RESTful API.

The `mini mongo` on the client is pure javascript and does not require a server connection. But there is no easy way to keep data in the `mini mongo` database without setting up a publish-subscribe link via DDP.

The packages like [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) assume there is a server side.

In developing you app, you will have to run the meteor server app in order to be able to serve the refreshed application every time a code change happens.