# meteor 1.0 without mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to use Meteor 1.0.x without the mongo package? The same question was asked [Meteor without mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545905/meteor-without-mongo) but the solution doesn't work anymore.

I've found that meteor-platform, application-configuration, autoupdate, routepolicy and webapp packages have a mongo dependency. You can reproduce the issue like this:

```
meteor create app_without_mongo
cd app_without_mongo

meteor remove autopublish insecure

PACKAGES_TO_ADD=$(meteor remove meteor-platform | grep 'removed from your project' | cut -d' ' -f1 |grep -v mongo |grep -v meteor-platform | grep -v application-configuration | grep -v autoupdate | grep -v routepolicy | grep -v webapp | tr -s '\n' ' ')


meteor add `echo $PACKAGES_TO_ADD`  

cat .meteor/versions| grep mongo # it only returns minimongo@1.0.6


meteor
    [[[[[ ~/mdsol/repos/meteor_test/app_without_mongo ]]]]]

    => Started proxy.
    => Started MongoDB.
    W20150114-18:01:42.960(0)? (STDERR) Program has no main() function.
=> Exited with code: 1
W20150114-18:01:46.211(0)? (STDERR) Program has no main() function.
=> Exited with code: 1
W20150114-18:01:47.442(0)? (STDERR) Program has no main() function.
=> Exited with code: 1
    => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Can you post , what is not wokring? meaning what errors you are getting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you have removed the `webapp` package, which is the main package that runs your Meteor app.