# Using TingoDB within a Meteor application in development and production mode

Tags: meteor, tingodb

I am trying to use TingoDB instead of MongoDB in a Meteor application I wrote for easier deployment.

I have been looking at the answer given here [Meteor without mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545905/meteor-without-mongo/19439847#19439847)

However, this isn't proving to be so easy.  For one thing, I would very much like to try and use (and debug) TingoDB in my development environment, not a bundled "production" environment.  Hopefully when I bundle it for production the new "mongo-livedata.js" would be included too.

My biggest issue so far is that I have NO idea (and I've tried tracing and poking around Meteor) where the devil Meteor is getting the "correct" mongo-livedata.js package.  I am hoping to be able to somehow "override" said package so I can "hack" away on it in safety and only for the single application I need it for.  So far where Meteor is loading this for development has eluded me greatly.  Let alone how I can, for this application, safely override it.

This is Meteor 1.1.02 -- the platform I am developing on is Mac OS X but I don't think that makes too much of a difference.

TIA!

Update: Using demeteorizer found the file in question now (mongo.js) and the similar code.  However, changing over to TingoDB has now made the application non-reactive to data changes, rather the reason I was using Meteor in the first place.  No idea why it's no longer reactive. :(